# NGINX Rewrite rule, passing part of the URL to PHP - Wishlist Member

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

In Nginx, how can I select the bold part of the URL below? 2013 and 12 are relative to the date so the rule needs to be flexible to work future locations.

example.com/wp-content/uploads/**2013/12/sometime.pdf**

The end result should look something like: **index.php?method=2013/12/sometime.pdf**

**Current rewrite rule**

I have tried with the following but this will only return the last letter of the URL.

```
rewrite ^/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/sometime.pdf /index.php?method=$1
```

Thanks!

Comment: Just give an example URL with index.php.

Comment: Sorry Jenson, I don't think I understand what you want.

Comment: What you're trying to achieve actually? Like grabbing '2013/12/sometime.pdf' and appends into index.php?

Comment: I need a rule that is going to redirect anything in the uploads folder. Passing 2013/12 and the file name to php method.

The end result would be something like:
**index.php?method=2013/12/sometime.pdf**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This expression will rewrite anything in the uploads folder, without a known extension, and passes the two parts of the URL as required:-

```
rewrite ^/wp-content/uploads/(.*)\.(?!css|js|png|jpe?g|gif)(.*)$ /index.php?method=$1.$2
```

**$1**, i.e. the first "**`(.*)`**" is anything between /wp-content/uploads/ and the . of the file extension.

**$2**, i.e. the second "**`(.*)`**" is anything after the matched . of the file extension,

Negative look aheads are the trick here: (**?!**.....)

Comment: Sorry Darren, no luck.

Comment: rewrite ^/wp-content/uploads/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/(.*)$ /index.php?method=$1

I would of thought something like this could work. But nginx is saying the line isn't terminated properly.

Comment: Minor alteration, added the redirect flag to the rewrite rule which:
`rewrite ^/wp-content/uploads/(.*)\.(?!css|js|png|jpe?g|gif)(.*)$ /index.php?method=$1.$2 redirect;
`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any specifics for the URL , you can do a normal location block, with a tiny bit of regex

```
location ^~ /wp-content/uploads/(.*) {
  try_files /index.php?method=$1 =404;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mohammad, Darren had a bit more information to go on with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

To use the wishlist member plugin in wordpress with nginx, add the following rule to parse files through the wlmfile method and apply the correct permissions.

```
location / {
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    rewrite ^/wp-content/uploads/(.*)\.(?!css|js|png|jpe?g|gif)(.*)$ /index.php?wlmfile=$1.$2 redirect;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
}
```